# Calculating probability of a time-series probability crossing a threshold

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

(Please feel free to suggest a better title -- I'm still not sure what to call this in the first place.)

I'm having trouble getting my head wrapped around a time-series stochastics problem I've run into. I think the main issue I'm having is that I don't know what area of statistics I need to be digging into to solve it. I've tried my best to break it down into the basic statistics terminology that I do remember -- feel free to let me know if I need to add or correct anything:

I'm trying to solve for *z*:

- *x*, *y*, and *z* are probabilities
- *S* is a time-series variable following a stochastic process that is close to normal, but with skew and kurtosis
- *K* is an upper limit for *S* that we pick at time 0; *K* > *S* at time 0
- *x* is the probability that *S* will be above *K* at time *t*; we don't calculate *x* -- it's provided by a third party; they don't publish skew or kurtosis, we might be able to get a stdev estimate
- *x* is recalculated and republished by the third party at each time tick
- *y* is a lower limit for *x* that we pick at time 0; *y* < *x* at time 0
- *z* is the probability of *x* crossing below *y* before time *t*

Given this information, can anyone see a way to calculate *z*?

It seems like, given that the inputs are already expressed in terms of probabilities, we should not need to know stdev, skew, or kurtosis... or am I completely confused?

**Simplified Example:**

Hydrologists estimate that there is an *x*=40% probability of a particular property being underwater exactly 10 years from now. An insurer writes a 10-year insurance contract for that property, specifying that no premium is due, and no coverage will start, unless and until the hydrologists' estimate first drops below *y*=30%.

What is the probability that coverage will start before the contract expires in 10 years?

I keep wanting to do simple things like *z* = 1 - (*x* - *y*), but that doesn't look right.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, after thinking about it a while...  I think the reason I'm having trouble figuring this out is that, in order to get *z*, I would need to know the stdev of *x*.  Alternatively, I'd need the stdev of the stdev of *S*.

I'd welcome any disagreement with that conclusion.  ;-)